# How can I speed up the loading speed of my AssetImage?

Tags: flutter, image, flutter-layout, loading

My image size is quite small which is about 50kb but it seems to load longer than I expected it would be, so my app doesn't load up that prettily as I would imagined. Any way I could speed it up?
`

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:egarment2/pages/home_page.dart';
import 'package:egarment2/sign_in.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override

  // void initState() {
  //   super.initState();
  //   Timer(
  //     const Duration(seconds: 3),
  //     () {
  //       Navigator.pushReplacement(
  //         context,
  //         MaterialPageRoute(
  //           builder: (context) => HomePage(),
  //         ),
  //       );
  //     },
  //   );
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        // color: const Color(0xFFf65d46),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/bg.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              'assets/images/logo.png',
              width: 75,
              height: 75,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 25,
            ),
            const Text(
              'E-Garment',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 30),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`

I tried compressing the image size which originally was 200 something kb to 50kb (current size) but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [`precacheImage`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html):

```dart
class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
   final _image = AssetImage('assets/images/bg.jpg');

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    precacheImage(_image, context);
    
    // Add your own initState code here
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    precacheImage(_image, context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: _image,
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ),

        // ...
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I meant the AssetImage on the Container's DecorationImage widget that loads up longer. Plus when I finally finished this splash screen UI, I would have to un-comment the initial void initState (){} which will create 2 initState(s) in the code. Thank you for the tip though!

Comment: @BryantAnthony It works the same with your AssetImage, just create a variable, precacheImage is taking an ImageProvider as its parameter which AssetImage is part of.
My initState was made to avoid bloating the code sample with unecessary commented code, nothing stops you from adding the single line I've used into your own.

Comment: @BryantAnthony I've updated the code sample to show you what it would be for your background asset.